# flutter build apk --release fails while running flutter build apk — debug works fine

Tags: firebase, flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-animation

**FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'apple_sign_in'.

> SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
  BUILD FAILED in 1s**

Comment: Show your local.properties file

Comment: hello bro @ProblematicDude
can we connect on google meet if possible

Comment: Try replacing it with the absolute path. Like `C:\Users......`

Comment: not exist in my project local.properties

Comment: Difficult to do meet at present. :(

Comment: ok bro @ProblematicDude